# Regular Expression to find a GUID string in a txt file with "id=" attached to it

Tags: c#, regex

The code below works well and the goal is to find a GUID string inside a XML file. So it will find the string `A03DD607-90BF-4077-ADA8-C6E76F9D4759` for instance but now I am trying to change the regular expression to only find:

`id="A03DD607-90BF-4077-ADA8-C6E76F9D4759"`

rather than

`A03DD607-90BF-4077-ADA8-C6E76F9D4759`

Here is my code:

```
    //obtain all GUIDs in the XML file
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(xmlFile))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            MatchCollection guids = Regex.Matches(s, @"(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}");
            for (int i = 0; i < guids.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(guids[i].Value);
                guidList.Add(guids[i].Value.ToUpper());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `//obtain all GUIDs in the XML file` Why not just use the XML parser built in to .NET instead of Regex? Using [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the query would just be `*[@id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to replace your corresponding code line:

```
MatchCollection guids = Regex.Matches(s, @"id=""\{?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}}?""");
```

In C# [*verbatim* string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) (see Point 2 at this link), that look like `@"..."`, a literal quotation mark must be doubled.

The `{0,1}` limiting quantifier can be safely changed into `?` (*1 or 0 occurrences*).

The `-` char outside of character classes (not inside `[...]` construct) do not have to be escaped.

See the [**regex demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=id%3d%22%5c%7b%3f%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b8%7d-%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b4%7d-%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b4%7d-%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b4%7d-%5b0-9a-fA-F%5d%7b12%7d%7d%3f%22&i=some+id%3d%2212345678-abcd-ab12-12ab-12345a7b9012%7d%22).

Comment: @LeresAldtai I improved the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I would defer the recognition of a textual `Guid` to `Guid.TryParse()`. That reduces your regular expression to something like this:

```
private const RegexOptions rxOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                                     | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
                                     | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
                                     ;

private static readonly Regex rxGuidId = new Regex( @"id=""(?<guid>[^""]+)""", rxOptions );
```

Then you could do it all in LINQ, like this:

```
private static Guid[] ExtractGuidsFromText( string s )
{
  return rxGuidId
         .Matches( s ?? "" )
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Where( m => m.Success )
         .Select( m => {
           Guid instance;
           bool validGuid = Guid.TryParse( m.Groups["guid"].Value , out instance ) ;
           return validGuid ? (Guid?)instance : (Guid?)null ;
         })
         .Where( g => g.HasValue )
         .Select( g => g.Value )
         .ToArray()
         ;
}
```

The LINQ solution is more verbose, less elegant, slower and uses more memory than doing it in the straightforward, simple way:

```
private static IEnumerable<Guid> ExtractGuidsFromText( string s )
{
  for ( Match m = rxGuidId.Match( s ?? "" ) ; m.Success ; m = m.NextMatch() )
  {
    Guid instance;
    bool parsed = Guid.TryParse( m.Groups["guid"].Value , out instance ) ;
    if ( parsed ) yield return instance;
  }
}
```

But since you've got an XML file, you could of course, use the built-in .Net support for XML and either select your node set via Xpath ( `//@id` ) ought to do it, just discard those nodes that don't have a valid GUID.

Or you could use an XML reader and find them lazily:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadGuidsFromXml( TextReader input )
{
  using ( XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create( input ) )
  {
    while ( reader.Read() )
    {
      if ( reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element ) continue ;

      for ( bool hasAttributes = reader.MoveToFirstAttribute() ; hasAttributes ; hasAttributes = reader.MoveToNextAttribute() )
      {
        if ( !string.Equals( reader.Name , "id" , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) continue ;

        Guid guid;
        if ( Guid.TryParse( reader.Value , out guid ) )
        {
          yield return guid;
        }

      }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for all your suggestion. I like them specially because you are parsing the Guid but TryParse wont work for me because we cannot use .Net4 yet :(